# Vue.js/Express.js :: Как правильно передавать токен на сервер в заголовках?

Tags: vue.js, express, token

Стек: **vue.js** + **express.js**

В **server.js** настроен и работает **CORS**.
C **API**/**CRUD** запросами **CORS** работает прекрасно.

**http.js**

```js
import Axios from 'axios';

export default Axios.create({

    withCredentials: true,
    baseURL: 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/api',
    timeout: 5000,
    headers: {

        'Content-type': 'application/json'
    }
});
```

**products.vue**

```js
import http from '../http.js';

//...

http.post('/auth/signin', data)
    .then(response => {

        const answer = response.data;
        
        if (response.data.state === 'success') {

           //...

        }
    })
    .catch(e => {

        console.log(e);
    });
```

**server.js**

```js
//...

// Load CORS
const cors = require('cors');
const corsOptions = {

    credentials: true,
    origin: 'http://mydomen.ru',
    allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type'],
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

//...
```

Answer (score 0):

РЕШЕНИЕ [подсказал Антон Спирин @rockon404]:

```js
headers: {
  'Content-type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
},
```

и подправить блок CORS сервера

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]